# ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 9 is different from 10)

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to write a simple python code that predicts the workload in an edge server, but it gives me this error:

> ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 9 is different from 10)

on this line of code: `model = np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ y`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(42)

# Define edge resource function
def edge_resources(t):
    return 100*np.exp(-0.01*t)

# Define simulation parameters
num_steps = 100
time_step = 0.1
prediction_horizon = 10

# Initialize resource and prediction arrays
resource_array = np.zeros(num_steps) #100
prediction_array = np.zeros(num_steps - prediction_horizon) #90

# Simulate resource and prediction
for i in range(num_steps):
    # Get current resource
    t = i*time_step
    resource_array[i] = edge_resources(t) #100
    
    # Predict remaining resources for future time steps
    if i >= prediction_horizon:
        # Get past and future resources
        past_resources = resource_array[i-prediction_horizon:i] # 
        future_resources = resource_array[i:i+prediction_horizon] #
        
        # Fit linear model to predict future resources
        X = np.arange(prediction_horizon).reshape(-1, 1)
        y = future_resources.reshape(-1, 1)
        model = np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ y
        
        # Store predicted resources
        prediction_array[i-prediction_horizon] = model[0, 0]

# Plot results
plt.plot(np.arange(num_steps)*time_step, resource_array, label='Edge Resources')
plt.plot(np.arange(prediction_horizon, num_steps)*time_step, prediction_array, label='Prediction')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Edge Resources')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you investigate the shapes of all matrices involved, which of them is different from what you expect?

Comment: If `i` becomes too large, `resource_array[i:i+prediction_horizon]` may have less than `prediction_horizon` items.

Comment: I think Michael has it: You need to change `if i >= prediction_horizon:` to `if prediction_horizon <= i < num_steps-prediction_horizon:` (or, you know, bake those boundaries into the `range` you're generating `i` from, rather than filtering after the fact).